# function invocation in render function

Tags: react-native

i want use single component.with that i will move another pages with out using navigation. i want use render function like if index=0 it will navigate to 1st page if index will be 1 i will navigate to 2nd page etc.
in my code if i click the next button nothing is happening.

```
onNext = () => {
  for(let i=0;i<=3;i++){
    this.goTopage(this.state.index +1); 
  }
}

onPrev = () => {
  this.goTopage(this.state.index -1);
}

onSkip = () => {
  this.setState({mainApp:true})
}
onDone =()=>{
  this.setState({mainApp:true})
}
goTopage =(pageNum)=>{
  this.setState({index: pageNum });
}
onNext =()=>{
  for(let i=0;i<=3;i++){
    this.goTopage(this.state.index +1); 
  }
}
onPrev =()=>{
  this.goTopage(this.state.index -1);
}
<Button
  onPress={this.onNext}
  title="Next "
  type="clear"
  titleStyle={{ color: 'black', fontSize: 24 }} 
/>
```

if i click the next button it is not moving to another screen

Comment: This is normal. Because you just add number to a state variable every time you press the button. Please show your navigation code.

Comment: Also, calling onNext will setState 3 times, and will always have index=3 when done. You also have duplicated code

Comment: i dont want to use navigation with out navigation i want to move.for example in render function i will write such as if index=1 then it will moves to 2nd page like that